# Search with multi filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question here. In common shopping cart sites have the function search for product with multiple filters. For example I'm searching for sport gear with some filters like this:

- Manufacturer

  - [**x**] Nike
  - Adidas
  - Umbro
- Options

  - Size

    - [**x**] S
    - [**x**] M
    - L
  - Color

    - [**x**] White
    - Yellow
    - Red
    - [**x**] Blue

Here's my mapping

```
PUT test/product/_mapping
{
    "product":{
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string", "store":"yes"},
            "manufacturer" {"type": "string}
            "options" : {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some test data

```
POST test/product/1
{
    "name": "Shirt 1",
    "manufacturer": "Adidas",
    "options":[
            {
                "Color" : ["Red", "Green"]
            },
            {
                "Size" : ["S","M","L"]
            }
        ],
    "price":250000
}

POST test/product/2
{
    "name": "Shirt 2",
    "manufacturer": "Nike",
    "options":[
            {
                "Color" : ["Blue", "Green", "White"]
            },
            {
                "Size" : ["S", "L", "XL"]
            }
        ],
    "price":100000
}

POST test/product/3
{
    "name": "Shirt 3",
    "manufacturer": "Umbro",
    "options": [
            {
                "Color" : ["Red"]
            },
            {
                "Size" : ["S","XXL"]
            }
        ],
    "price": 300000
}
```

With this query, everything's fine

```
POST test/product/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "match_all": {}
           },
           "filter": {
               "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                           "nested": {
                              "path": "options",
                              "filter": {
                                  "bool": {
                                      "must": [ 
                                         {
                                            "terms": {
                                               "options.Color": [
                                                  "white"
                                               ]
                                            }
                                         }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              }
                           }
                       },
                       {
                           "term": {
                              "manufacturer": "nike"
                           }
                       }
                    ]
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

But, if I add more condition in Options filter, i get no result

```
POST test/product/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
                "match_all": {}
           },
           "filter": {
               "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                           "nested": {
                              "path": "options",
                              "filter": {
                                  "bool": {
                                      "must": [ 
                                         {
                                            "terms": {
                                               "options.Color": [
                                                  "white"
                                               ]
                                            }
                                         },

                                         {
                                            "terms": {
                                               "options.Size": [
                                                  "s"
                                               ]
                                            }
                                         }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              }
                           }
                       },
                       {
                           "term": {
                              "manufacturer": "nike"
                           }
                       }
                    ]
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know whether i'm wrong in mapping or my query, or can you show me what's the best way to create mapping in this scenario. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the usage of the `nested` type. Your `nested` filter is not evaluated over all children altogether but on every child individually. Since you do not have a *single* nested object, that satisfies your filter (having both, `Color` and `Size`), you're not getting any results. You have two options:

1. merge those individual nested objects together

   ```
   POST test/product/1
   {
       "name": "Shirt 1",
       "manufacturer": "Adidas",
       "options":[
           {
               "Color" : ["Red", "Green"],
               "Size" : ["S","M","L"]
           }
       ],
       "price":250000
   }
   ```

   Your mapping and query stays the same.
2. Do not use a `nested` type, but a simple `object` type. You have to change your mapping for `options`:

   ```
   PUT test/product/_mapping
   {
       "product":{
           "properties" : {
               "options" : {
                   "type": "object"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And drop the `nested` filter:

   ```
   POST test/product/_search
   {
      "query": {
         "filtered": {
            "query": {
               "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "options.Color": [
                              "white"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "options.Size": [
                              "s"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "manufacturer": "nike"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

   But your data can stay the same.

Nested objects are really for different structured data. If you were to have something like

```
"options":[
    {
        "Color" : "Blue",
        "Size": "S"
    },
    {
        "Color": "Red",
        "Size" : "L"
    }
]
```

And you want to filter for items, that are both, *Blue* and *S*, then you would have to use a nested filter.

Comment: Thank you for your help, all 2 solutions worked. I have a question, my 'options' field does not only have 2 properties 'Color' and 'Size', these attribute will be created depend on Product, for example i have new product with Color = ['Red'], Size =['M'] , Something = ['A','B'].... Is it OK if I set type Object for Options?

Comment: Sure, that would work, `object` is the default type for nested data. Keep in mind, that it flattens your data, which effectively becomes `{"options.Color": ["Red", "Blue"], "options.Something": ["A", "B"]}` and so on. So, as long if you're not interested about _which_ `Color` belongs to _which_ `Something`, `object` is fine. More on that on the elasticsearch blog: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/